# А можно ли без засыпания в JScript?

Tags: jscript

Возьмем приводящийся на каждом шагу пример применения метода SendKeys:

```
theCalculator = WshShell.Exec("calc");           
// Запустим калькулятор
WScript.Sleep(3000);                             
// Ждем 3 секунды
WshShell.AppActivate(theCalculator.
ProcessID);   // Активируем окно 
//запущенного приложения
WshShell.SendKeys("1{+}2~")                   
// Пошлём 1 + 2 Enter
WshShell.SendKeys("1")                          
// Пошлём 1 
WScript.Sleep(3000);                            
// Ждем 3 секунды
WshShell.SendKeys("{+}")                        
// Пошлём +
WScript.Sleep(3000);                            
// Ждем 3 секунды
WshShell.SendKeys("2")                         
// Пошлём 2 
WScript.Sleep(3000);                                 
// Ждем 3 секунды
WshShell.SendKeys("~")                          
// Пошлём Enter
```

первый WScript.Sleep(3000); , очевидно, предназначен для того, чтобы дождаться запуска калькулятора и уже после этого продолжать работу. Но, в зависимости от загруженности процессора, мне кажется, время запуска приложения может меняться. А вот можно ли, например, в данном случае что-то написать в код, чтобы работа скрипта продолжилась точно после появления на мониторе окна калькулятора? возможно, с привлечением батника. Наподобие
     WshShell.Run("lyx " + objArgs(0), 1, 
     true); 
хотя, это, естественно, не то, что нужно. Или без тяжелой артиллерии, там, Питон, Си здесь не обойтись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример скрипта, который запускается точно после появления на мониторе окна калькулятора.

Файл сохраните с расширением *.js, кодировка ANSI или Юникод. Тест на Windows-7-64

```js
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");

KL = true;

//------------ Search window "Калькулятор" ---------

while (KL) {
  if (WshShell.AppActivate("Калькулятор")) {
    WriteWord();
    KL = false;
  }
  WScript.Sleep(500);
}

function WriteWord() {
  WshShell.SendKeys("{4}");
WScript.Sleep(500);
  WshShell.SendKeys("{+}");
WScript.Sleep(500);
  WshShell.SendKeys("{6}");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
}
```

Comment: @ Максим Белов, ВЫСШИЙ ПИЛОТАЖ!!!! КЛАСС!!! Это то, что надо! Большое спасибо!!!

Comment: Не пойму, в обращениях использовать @ только, когда ник написан английскими буквами?